# Vue passing a event handler to a component to another component - Invalid handler for event "updatefilters": got undefined

Tags: vue.js

I have some nested components. Here is my top level component that sites in the page HTML:

```
<advanced-options-model ... @updatefilters="updateFilters"></advanced-options-model>
```

Notice how updateFilters is passed into the component. Here is the `advanced-options-model` component and its dependent `filter-checkboxes`:

```
var filterCheckBoxes = {
    template: `
    <div>
        <fieldset v-for="name in names">
            <legend v-text="name"></legend>
            <label v-for="...">
                <input type="checkbox" ... @change="$emit('updatefilters')">
                {{value}} ({{count}})
            </label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    `,
    props: ["updatefilters", ...]
};

var advancedOptionsModal = {
    components: {
        "filter-checkboxes": filterCheckBoxes
    },
    template: `
    <div class="modal" ...>
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                ...
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <filter-checkboxes ... @updatefilters="updatefilters"></filter-checkboxes>
                </div>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    `,
    props: ["updatefilters", ...]
};

Vue.component('advanced-options-model', advancedOptionsModal);
```

Actually, if I remove the `@updatefilters="updatefilters"` in advancedOptionsModal  I don't see any errors so the issue seems to be in this template. However, within this template I pass this same function to the `filter-checkboxes` component:

```
<filter-checkboxes ... @updatefilters="updatefilters"></filter-checkboxes>
```

Here is the exact error message I'm seeing in inspector:

```
vue.js:616 [Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "updatefilters": got undefined

found in

---> <FilterCheckboxes>
       <AdvancedOptionsModel>
         <Root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're not *passing* `updateFilters` into `advanced-options-model` component, you're binding `updateFilters` method on `updatefilters` event.

To bind parameters to component you should use `v-bind:...` or just `:...`. Shorthand `@...` is for `v-on:...`.

If you want to "bubble" `updatefilters` event from `filter-checkboxes` component to your root component you should do it like this:

```js
var filterCheckBoxes = {
    template: `
    <div>
        <fieldset v-for="name in names">
            <legend v-text="name"></legend>
            <label v-for="...">
                <input type="checkbox" ... @change="$emit('updatefilters')">
                {{value}} ({{count}})
            </label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    `
};

var advancedOptionsModal = {
    components: {
        "filter-checkboxes": filterCheckBoxes
    },
    template: `
    <div class="modal" ...>
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                ...
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <filter-checkboxes ... @updatefilters="$emit('updatefilters')"></filter-checkboxes>
                </div>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    `
};

Vue.component('advanced-options-model', advancedOptionsModal);
```

And somewhere else:

```html
<advanced-options-model ... @updatefilters="updateFilters"></advanced-options-model>
```

```js
methods: {
  updateFilters() {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I've made that change. For some reason, filter-checkboxes isn't outputting even if all I put in the template is `...`. It's rendering strangely as a text value of `">`. I've tried using even just a self-closing tag e.g. `<filter-checkboxes :names="['subject', 'delivery']" :availablefilters="availablefilters" :activefilters="activefilters" @updatefilters="$emit('updatefilters')/>` Does my code look OK with regard for having components within components? I'll perhaps raise another ticket as the issue I was having with this one was answered.

Comment: @Martyn You forgot closing `"` in `@updatefilters=...`

Comment: Ahh! Thank you, I thought I'd checked thoroughly. Yeh working now.